Kafka connection loss due to "Cannot change principals during re-authentication"
I'm encountering an issue with Kafka while using EKS Pod Identity, where after some time, the connection to Kafka is lost with the following error:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Cannot change principals during re-authentication

Same issue has been mentioned here and here and here
They all suggest to set AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME env var, and they claim it solves they issue.
However:
"This pops up also when you use EKS-pod-identity and the session name changes. And you can't as of now set a static session name."
That's exactly our case, so we cannot use the environment variable approach.
We are using Spring Kafka + reactor-kafka
We have seen this configuration:
@Component
public class KafkaFactoryCustomizer {

    KafkaFactoryCustomizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(
            container -> container.getContainerProperties().setRestartAfterAuthExceptions(true)
        );
    }
}

But I didn't find any documentation and I have no idea if that could work given our current stack.
To create ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate we use:
@Bean
public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, byte[]> createKafkaReceiver(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
   ReceiverOptions<String, byte[]> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(
        kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(null)
   );

   return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(
      receiverOptions.subscription(topics)
   );
}

